# How does iOS 13 connect multiple AirPods at the same time using Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, airpods

I’ve recently discovered that iOS 13 allow you to connect and play music on multiple AirPods synchronized (almost) perfectly. As far as I’m concerned the AirPods are using Bluetooth which only allows you to have one connection

Answer (score 0):

You can have several Bluetooth devices connected at a time.

From [How Does Bluetooth Work](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bluetooth-basics/all#how-bluetooth-works):

> Bluetooth networks (commonly referred to as piconets) use a master/slave model to control when and where devices can send data. In this model, a single master device can be connected to up to seven different slave devices. Any slave device in the piconet can only be connected to a single master.